# Can Desert Island's 'Trap' card be used on multiple targets affected by fate?

Tags: desert-island

In the game [Desert Island](http://gorillaboardgames.com/our-games/desert-island/), the *Trap* Scavenge Card reads:

> Expend when a Bear, Monkey, or Rat Fate event happens. The target
>   gains 3 food instead of suffering the Fate consequences.

If multiple targets are affected by the fate, can the card be use to convert the fate to food for all of the targets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desert Island's designer, Jeff Siadek replied to a similar question on boardgamegeek.com that [only one target is protected by the trap](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1529877/need-some-rules-clarification). Cut throat!

Comment: Why all the downvotes? If this answer were just updated to include a link to that BGG source, I'd call it a perfect answer.

Comment: Jeff Siadek is the designer of Desert Island.  This answer is correct and provides an answer to the question.

Comment: If this answer is based on one posted on BGG it would be nice to have the link to show what was posted so this answer can get proper credit.